# html menu animation completely broken?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to teach myself front end development through online resources like w3schools.com and code academy and I have the very most basics down in HTML and CSS. I started a little portfolio web page project to test myself and see what I don't know. while following along with a menu icon animation tutorial on w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_icon_js I got stuck when my code animation didn't want to run. I copy and pasted the code from the tutorial into a new visual studio's file and it ran with no problem. I believe that it has to do with the fact that my Javascript code is in a different file and i linked it to HTML code improperly but when I moved it around it still didn't work so I'm at a complete lost as to what could be the problem. any help is much appreciated

HTML Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="main page.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Cal's Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
    <script src="main page.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS Code:

```
    .container {
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
width: 35px;
height: 5px;
background-color: #333;
margin: 6px 0;
transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

JavaScript Code:

```
    function myFunction(x) {x.classlist.toggle("change");}
```

Comment: I suppose your css is improperly linked. Why do you have "main" in your href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function must be:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
        x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

It's classList with capital "L" not "l".

Answer (score 0):

looks like your problem is in the script tag,
`<script src="main page.js"></script>`
should probably be
`<script src="main/page.js"></script>`?

Comment: i forgot to mention that the name of all 3 files are main_page.html, main_page.css, and main_page.js but that was an error that i did not correct. even still though the code isn't working. thank you for the help

Comment: definitely sounds like the css and js files aren't making their way into the browser, try inline style and script first, once you know the code works, then separate the files.

Answer (score 0):

I looked here where the error is:
You mistakenly referenced the file, completely normal.
To make it work, you must navigate between the folders and select the file.
To do that, in my opinion, you should start by typing a "./" and then let VSCode (for example) show you which folders/files are in that directory.

Your JavaScript code have a mistake on "`classlist`", should be `x.classList.toggle("change");` like W3Schools teach. That piece of code is CamelCase.

Here is the correct code, taking into account that you have a folder in the root of your project called "`main`", with the files "`page.css`" and "`page.js`"

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./main/page.css">
```

and

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./main/page.js"></script>
```